# Jquery startdate enddate datepicker for dynamically created textbox inside gridview

Tags: jquery, gridview, datepicker

i am working on requirement which has Startdate and enddate Textboxes dynamically created on grid view. while clicking start date and end date datepicker has to open .for end date it has to disable dates based on startdate. its working fine outside gridview.;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {        
         $("#<%=txtStartTime.ClientID%>").datepicker({
             changeMonth: true,
             changeYear: true,
             minDate: 0, 
             maxDate: "+365D",
             onSelect: function () {
                 var minFromDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                 $("#<%=txtEndTime.ClientID%>").datepicker("option", "minDate", minFromDate);  //dates less than the selected from date will be disabled in "txtToDate" textbox
                 var maxToDate = "+3Y";
                 $("#<%=txtEndTime.ClientID%>").datepicker("option", "maxDate", maxToDate) //maxToDate set to 3 years from FromDate
             },
             onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                 var validDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", $("#<%=txtStartTime.ClientID%>").datepicker('getDate'));
                 $("#<%=txtStartTime.ClientID%>").datepicker('setDate', validDate);
             },
             dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
         }, "showAnim", $(this).val());

         $("#<%=txtEndTime.ClientID%>").datepicker({
             changeMonth: true,
             changeYear: true,
             minDate: 0, // '0' means current date
             maxDate: "+5Y",
             onSelect: function () {
                 var maxToDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                 $("#<%=txtStartTime.ClientID%>").datepicker("option", "maxDate", maxToDate) //set the "MaxDate" attribute for "txtFromDate" in onSelect event of "txtToDate" textbox
             },
             onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                 var validDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", $("#<%=txtEndTime.ClientID%>").datepicker('getDate'));
                 $("#<%=txtEndTime.ClientID%>").datepicker('setDate', validDate);
             },
             dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
         }, "showAnim", $(this).val());
     });

</script>
```

dynamically created Textbox Ids are like below

D3Step1_gridview__ctl2_txtStartDate
D3Step1_gridview__ctl2_txtEndDate

D3Step1_gridview__ctl3_txtStartDate
D3Step1_gridview__ctl3_txtEndDate